# Using a batch script to listen to and sent strings to wireless module

Tags: command-prompt

I have an issue with a wireless module that require me to restart it from time to time.
The data stops transmitting and the module needs a restart command. 
I would like to automate this process.

I was wondering if it is possible to use a batch script (cmd.exe) to listen to the communication port, and test for a spesific string, and then send a reset command on the wireless modules service port, if the strings should ever stop.

I am not looking for help writing the code, just some clearity as to the limitations of a batch script.

Comment: There's a tool available from Microsoft called `devcon.exe` that can disable and re-enable hardware.  It is a device manager command line tool.  You could script it to run every 10 minutes or hourly, depending on the severity of your problem, or script it to run when a PING fails to an external site.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit unsure about the capabilities of windows cmd, but with powershell this should definitely be possible. For the networking part you could probably even use netcat in server mode (this is what I'd use on Linux).

Cheers
Hendrik